# Count rows per hour in SQL Server with full date-time value as result

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I count the number of rows per hour in SQL Server with full date-time as result.

I've already tried this, but it returns only the hours

```
SELECT DATEPART(HOUR,TimeStamp), Count(*)
FROM [TEST].[dbo].[data]
GROUP BY DATEPART(HOUR,TimeStamp)
ORDER BY DATEPART(HOUR,TimeStamp)
```

Now the result is:

```
Hour   Occurrence 
----   ----------
10     2157
11     60740
12     66189
13     77096
14     90039
```

But I need this:

```
Timestamp               Occurrence
-------------------     ----------
2013-12-21 10:00:00     2157
2013-12-21 11:00:00     60740
2013-12-21 12:00:00     66189
2013-12-21 13:00:00     77096
2013-12-21 14:00:00     90039
2013-12-22 09:00:00     84838
2013-12-22 10:00:00     64238
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You actually need to round the `TimeStamp` to the hour.  In SQL Server, this is a bit ugly, but easy to do:

```
SELECT dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, TimeStamp), 0) as TimeStampHour, Count(*)
FROM [TEST].[dbo].[data]
GROUP BY dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, TimeStamp), 0)
ORDER BY dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, TimeStamp), 0);
```

Comment: Excellent. Indeed a bit ugly (certainly compared to MySQL)

Comment: This is really useful. Is there anyway to make the query return zero values for hours where no records where appended? Rather than skipping them in the results table? Thanks.

Comment: @Adam92 . . . That is another question.  You can do it, but the query looks a bit different.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, can you demonstrate how this can be done?

Comment: @Adam92 . . . If you have a question, then a question is an appropriate place to ask it, not a comment.

Comment: What would be the MySQL query for the above ?

Comment: @Biranchi . . . Questions should be asked as new questions, not in a comment.

Comment: When I tried this in my environment, it raised an exception because some rows had the value '0001-01-01 00:00:00' or '0001-01-01 12:00:00' in the CreatedOn column. The error was "Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value." A simple WHERE clause to exclude those values resolved the problem.