# T-SQL Get Rows Per Hour Regardless of Day

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Using the accepted answer found in this post [Count rows per hour in SQL Server with full date-time value as result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20719901/count-rows-per-hour-in-sql-server-with-full-date-time-value-as-result) I am able to get a count of records by the hour, however, I would like to make it so that the day does not matter.

How can I get a count of records by the hour of the day, regardless of what day the record is from?

For example, the following table:

```
+----------+-------------------------+
| instance |        datetime         |
+----------+-------------------------+
| A        | 2017-01-10 11:01:05.267 |
| B        | 2017-01-13 11:07:05.783 |
| C        | 2017-01-14 11:37:05.593 |
| D        | 2017-01-17 11:37:38.610 |
| E        | 2017-01-17 11:47:04.877 |
| F        | 2017-01-15 12:14:34.127 |
| G        | 2017-01-17 12:15:09.373 |
| H        | 2017-01-09 13:58:06.013 |
+----------+-------------------------+
```

Would result in the following dataset:

```
+-------------+-------------+
| recordCount |  timeStamp  |
+-------------+-------------+
|           5 | 11:00:00.00 |
|           2 | 12:00:00.00 |
|           1 | 13:00:00.00 |
+-------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Which version of sql server you are using ?

Comment: Why not remove the date from the datetime columns, setting it to 1900-01-01 for all rows? Then you would get the expected result.

Comment: @Prdp SQL Server 11

Comment: amazingly the query posted by the OP in the question you linked is exactly what you need here.

Comment: @DrydenLong - Run `select @@version` and tell you got as result. There is no `Sql Server 11`

Comment: @Prdp Sorry, to be more exact, it is Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5058.0 (X64)

Comment: @SeanLange Wow, that's what I get for skipping straight to the answers...

Comment: Well the good news is you really did find a relevant question to your situation. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [**`DATEPART`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx):

```
SELECT DATEPART(HOUR, [datetime]), COUNT(*)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY DATEPART(HOUR, [datetime])
```

The function returns an integer, essentially extracting the hour value from the `DATETIME` field.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `SQL SERVER 2012` or above then use `FORMAT`

```
SELECT Count(1) AS Recordcount,
       Format([datetime], 'HH:00:00')
FROM   yourtable
GROUP  BY Format([datetime], 'HH:00:00')
```

or `CONCAT` and `DATEPART`

```
SELECT Concat(Datepart(HOUR, [datetime]), ':00:00'),
       Count(*)
FROM   Yourtable
GROUP  BY Datepart(HOUR, [datetime])
```